# Правильный php код после сложного запроса mysql

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

Я очень прошу кому не тяжело (откликнитесь) отпишите как это нужно делать правильно, нигде не могу найти пример...
К примеру есть такая mysql таблица c названием Games:

```
Страна | Лига      | Игра                  // название полей

Италия | Кубок     | Ювентус - Милан
Англия | Чемпионат | Челси - Арсенал
Италия | Кубок     | Милан - Наполи
...
```

Нужно вывести к примеру так:

```
<h2> Италия </h2>
    <h3> Кубок </h3>
       <p> Ювентус - Милан </p>
       <p> Милан - Наполи </p>
       ...
<h2> Италия </h2>
    <h3> Чемпионат </h3>
       <p> Сантос - Казаывн </p>
       <p> Ауауав - Ппапакк </p>
       ...
<h2> Англия </h2>
    <h3> Чемпионат </h3>
       <p> Челси - Арсенал </p>
       ...
```

Теперь как это сделал бы я:

```
$content = '';
$unique_countrys_query = mysqli_query("select DISTINCT(Страна) from Games"); // узнаем страны
while($uc_result = mysqli_fetch_assoc($unique_country_query)) {
    $unique_league_query = mysqli_query("select DISTINCT(Лига) from Games WHERE Страна = '".$uc_result['Страна']."'"); // узнаем лиги в этой стране
    while($ul_result = mysqli_fetch_assoc($unique_league_query)) {
        $games_query = mysqli_query("SELECT игры FROM Games WHERE Страна = '".$uc_result['Страна']."' AND Лига = '".$ul_result['Лига']."'"); // Игры для Лиги в этой стране..
        $content .= "<h2> $uc_result['Страна'] </h2>";
        $content .= "<h3> $ul_result['Лига'] </h3>";
        while($g_result = mysqli_fetch_assoc($game_query)) {
            $content .= "<p> $g_result['Игра'] </p>";
        }
    }
}
echo $content;
```

Как я понял это НЕ правильно.
Вообщем так бы сделал я так как по другому не умею, но хочу научится читал про вложенные запросы, сложные запросы и т.д... но все равно не пойму как это реализовать, МНЕ БЫ пример на основе этого, как вот такой ЗАПРОС должен выглядеть и как ЭТОТ ЗАПРОС обработать на вывод(вывести на экран результат)...
Пример пожалуйста!!!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вот как бы сделала я:

```
$query = mysqli_query("SELECT * FROM Games;");
$res = array();
while($r = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query)) 
{
    $res[$r['Страна']][$r['Лига']][] = $r['Игра'];
}
```

В итоге получаем массив:

```
$res = array(
    'Италия' => array(
        'Чемпионат' => array(
             'Cантос - Казаывн',
             'Ауауав - Ппапакк'
         ),
         ...
    ),
    ...
);
```

Выводить его можно так

```
foreach ($res as $country => $lig)
{
    echo '<h2>' . $country. '</h2>';
    foreach ($lig as $lig_name => $content)
    {
        echo '<h3>' . $lig_name . '</h3>';
        foreach ($content as $item)
        {
           echo '<p>' . $item . '</p>';
        }
    }
}
```

Пара советов:

- принято называть колонки в БД на английском
- не нужно делать запросы в цикле, а тем более во вложенных циклах, старайтесь достать все данные одним запросом, а уже дальше можно с ними работать в сколько угодно вложенных циклах.

Comment: Спасибо вам, теперь я все понял!...